# recovery innodb table from either .idb file or mysqldump UTF-16 file

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently deleted rows from a innodb table which I now need to restore!

The table has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `myDatabase`.`myTable` (
  `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `chunk_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `filedata` longblob, 
PRIMARY KEY `PRIMARY` (`file_id`,`chunk_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I have 2 backups available to me;

a raw IBD file (2.2GB) and its matching .frm file. The servers ib_log file is only 48 MB, so I'm assuming all the information I need is within the IBD file.

I've tried creating a new mysql instance, creating a table with the same columns, discarding the tablespace then overwriting the .idb file with the 2.2GB copy, however when I try the command "IMPORT tablespace" I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1815 (HY000): Internal error: Cannot reset LSNs in table `myDatabase`.`myTable` : Data structure corruption
```

I'm not sure where I can restore the table with this error - there doesn't seem to be much about this from my research.

I do have another backup available, it was taken using mysqldump, however Powershell was used to create the backup, which has resulted in the backup being UTF-16 LE and not UTF-8 (mysqldump outputs UTF-8 but Powershell converts to UTF-16 LE when it writes to disk).

When I tried to import this SQL file I get the error "the charector set isn't supported", so I've used Powershell to convert the SQL file into UTF-8 using the following command:

```
Get-Content file.foo -Encoding Unicode | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 newfile.foo
```

Although I can import the resulting UTF-8 SQL backup, the blob data is currupt (although the other columns file_id, chunk_id are OK). I can't seem to figure out a way to convert the UTF-16 SQL backup to UTF-8 without screwing up the blob column, not sure if Powershell screwed up the blob column when it converted the mysqldump UTF-8 to UTF-16 when writing to disk.

Does it seem likely I'm able to recover this table via either the IDB file or the UTF-16 mysqldump file?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Hi open the mysqldump file by a text editor use notepad++ and search for the table name. After create statement you can find the records you needed. In a insert statement. Copy and paste those to the newly created table object in the data base.

Comment: Hi, I tried that and it didn't work. I insert the row, but the filedata column (the blob) is corrupt in someway.

When I export the database using command prompt, I get a UTF-8 .sql file, which works if I re-import the sql file.

When I export the database using Powershell I get a UTF-16 .sql file, which if I re-import into mysql the filedata rows are different, changed in some way.

I only have a UTF-16 version of the data I need though.